# How to measure the performance of LC3 assembly program?

Tags: performance, assembly, scripting, lc3

For examples, there are many LC3 assembly programs for a right shift, does it make sense to evaluate them based on how fast the programs would run? is there a way to embed an assembly program in a scripting language such as python to measure its speed?

Answer (score 0):

```
It can be measured indirectly via running a script:
1: create a script for lc3sim denoted as: lc3_run.txt
    #cat lc3_run.txt
        file test.obj
        c
    #

2. create a shell script denoted as: perf_test.sh
    #cat perf_test.sh
        set -x
        n=0
        while [ $n -lt 1000 ]
        do
            lc3sim  -s lc3_run.txt
            ((n+=1))
            echo $n
        done
     #chmod +x perf_test.sh
     #time ./perf_test.sh
        real    0m14.512s
        user    0m3.552s
        sys 0m3.304s

    #3. compare the run time to evaluate which one is faster under 
        same conditions (HW/SW)

For related reference: <a href="https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/357146/how-to-evaluate-efficiency-of-assembler-code "/> efficiency </a>
```

Comment: Given that each iteration took ~14ms, it's likely dominated by the time required to launch lc3sim. There's a lot of variability in that, which will likely make these numbers meaningless at best, and misleading at worst. You can explore this impact by making test.obj a do nothing at all, and run this many times, then try adding a very small amount of work to test.obj and try to measure it. Microbenchmarking (measuring the performance of small routines) is notoriously difficult on modern hardware, but at a minimum, you'll want to do the iterating inside of test.obj and launch it one time.

Comment: Related: Compare the size of the code you're testing to the code for bash's built-in `echo` that you're calling: https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/echo.def#L110-L202. (putchar can be pretty expensive by itself, but just think about the number of lines of code there). If the `echo` by itself is similar in size to the code under test, imagine how buried the timing you're interested is going to be.

Comment: (BTW, the link you provided is pretty good and correct. It's just that in the "embed the code snippets you want to compare into some benchmark program" step, you've embedded an entire launch of lc3sim, plus more, rather than just embedding the code snippet you wanted.)

Comment: Good suggestions, Thanks.